# Incorrect default value in Neovim: Cannot create backup file (add ! to overwrite)

Tags: vim, location, config, default-value, neovim

my neovim always shows this message after saving. `Cannot create backup file (add ! to overwrite)`

When I type `verbose set backupdir` the output is: `backupdir=.,~/.local/share/nvim/backup`, which is weird because It should be set up by default.

I made sure the folder exists. After I set the value in init.vim to `~/.local/share/nvim/backup`, then it worked. But I would like to know **where the problem started**.

Is there a location where neovim takes default values for unset variables? Maybe it was overwritten.

[my init.vim](https://pastebin.com/LzNah9Pn)

[**this** question did not help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8428210/7321103)

[**this**  one helped a little bit](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/issues/367)

Comment: Better suited for [Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/). Also, include your config file

Comment: Yes, I did not noticed that earlier, here is my init.vim  https://pastebin.com/LzNah9Pn 
thank you