# Windows 10: Can't make backup file (add ! to override)

Tags: windows, vim, windows-10

This is **not** a duplicate of:

- [Vim error E510: Can't make backup file (add ! to override)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664805/vim-error-e510-cant-make-backup-file-add-to-override), there are no spaces before or after my equal signs
- [Cannot create backup file(add ! to overwrite)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428210/cannot-create-backup-fileadd-to-overwrite)

My `.vimrc` in Windows is located at `C:\Proram Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc`.

I've added:

```
set undodir="C:/Program Files (x86)/Vim/undo//"
set backupdir="C:/Program Files (x86)/Vim/backup//"
set directory="C:/Program Files (x86)/Vim/swp//"
```

I have:

- Created the directories in question
- Ensured that my user has write permissions for the directory and every file in said directory
- Tried different formats for the directory, including using `/` instead of `\`, omitting `//` at the end of the directory, and escaping the spaces in `Program Files (x86)`

Despite all of this I still receive an E510 error upon saving. Can anyone help out? Doing things on Windows is so amazingly frustrating. :l

Comment: `C:/Program Files (x86)/Vim/` is off-limits. Any customisation is supposed to happen in `$HOME/vimfiles/`.

Comment: @romainl What do you mean "off-limits"? For whom is it off limits and how can I put it **on** limits?

Comment: For you. For me. For everyone. There is no point whatsoever in trying to put it **in** limits. `$HOME/vimfiles/` is where you configure Vim, end of the story.

Comment: @romainl Sorry, that doesn't really answer my question. Clearly it's not off limits to *everyone*, because there are files and folders there. I'm able to create files and folders in that folder; I'm able to otherwise do everything I can in any other folder. There **is** a point in my trying to put it on limits—the point is that, that's where I want those files to be stored.

What makes this folder off limits? Is there a setting or a registry key somewhere? A permission? I don't know where you're getting this "end of story" idea.

Comment: I don't use Windows but I have a lot of experience with Vim and its idiosyncrasies… and new users trying to do pointless things. Doing anything in that directory is likely to break Vim and to be overwritten during the next upgrade anyway. This is true on every system Vim runs on: it is designed to be fully customized in the user runtime, where, for example, you can't have the problem you are currently struggling with. So create your directories there and move on.

Comment: `:h :set-args` Apparently, you misuse command syntax.

Comment: @Matt Sorry, where is the misuse? `:h :set-args` says `:se[t] {option}={value}`, which is exactly what I have.